# Type casting in C++ with templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting

In *C++*, is there any way to simplify the expression below using (for instance) templates?

```
std::stringstream data;
if (data_type == types::UINT8) {
    uint8_t val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else if (data_type == types::UINT16) {
    uint16_t val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else if (data_type == types::UINT32) {
    uint32_t val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else if (data_type == types::UINT64) {
    uint64_t val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else if (data_type == types::INT8) {
    int8_t val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else if (data_type == types::INT16) {
    int16_t val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else if (data_type == types::INT32) {
    int32_t val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else if (data_type == types::INT64) {
    int64_t val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else if (data_type == types::FLOAT64) {
    double val;
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
    U.push_back(val);
} else {
    return false;
};
```

Comment: What is the variable `U`?

Comment: It really helps the people providing answers if your example is complete. Right now everyone who wants to answer has to first spend 2 minutes defining `data_type`, `U`, adding includes, wrapping all this in a function... (Well, if they want to check that their answer is valid/compiles, that is). You'll make everyone's life a lot easier if the code you provide compiles directly on e.g. https://godbolt.org (but do keep the code in the question).

Comment: Beware that endianness may break reading values with more than one byte unless they are written in a similar manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function template to do the read:

```
template<typename T>
void read(std::stringstream& data,TypeOfU& U){
  T val;
  data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
  U.push_back(val);
}
```

Then use a `switch`:

```
switch(data_type){
case types::INT64: read<int64_t>(data,u); break;
case types::FLOAT64: read<double>(data,u); break;
// etc.
}
```

Comment: The idea is clear, but your `read` takes two arguments and is passed none.

Comment: Exactly ! And as an alternative to a switch, it is also possible to define a `const std::array<std::pair<Type, readmethod_t>, N>` and then use a for loop to iterate the array.